# Sharing disk (LUN) between Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

There's a need for an easy and fast way to share files between two VMs. GlusterFS is too slow for a small files, NFS is a handful when it comes to HA.

Solution is to share independent disk between machines. Can this be a "normal" disk but in independent mode, or that needs to be RDM? If RDM, then what's the process to follow to install such share? Should I create PV(?), VG, LV, FS (as on normal disk) on one host and everything will be "detected" on second node? If not - kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is unclear.

In the overwhelming majority of cases having a block device shared between multiple machines/VMs is an overwhelmingly bad idea which will cause data corruption and instability (except where the media is read-only on BOTH systems) unless used with special filesystems designed with this in mind (like GFS or OCFS2)

LVM does not help here (PV's, VG's, LV's dont help).

Its unclear **exactly** what you are trying to do, and any solution is likely specific to your environment.  Have you considered using a FUSE filesystem to do something akin to NFS - maybe using a distributed/replicated database backend?  I do note this is very much a TANSTAFL problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David!Use case is: two VM's will share a drive (independent vmware disk) to store the application files on it. I thought about doing this via RDM disk with XFS/EXT4 filesystem. Like you mentioned, those are not distributed fs's, that's why I am wondering if that will even work. 
Our storage has no option to export NFS. Building separate NFS server in HA mode will introduce same problem with sharing a drive between nodes.

Comment: @JaxMitchell, what you are attempting will not work.  Depending on your use case, building an NFS server with Hot/warm standby (ie active-passive) should be a lot simpler then what you are attempting - particularly if you use something like DRBD or MARS and the NFS server is itself a VM.

Comment: Have you considered using something like OwnCloud/NextCloud to have dropbox-like semantics and simply replicate the data on write between the 2 systems?  This is not exactly what you are asking, but strikes me as being a good way of doing replication and avoiding many of the problems with split brain.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints Dave. I will def. check NextCloud drive option, just out of curiosity.
Do you have experience with nfs-ganesha? If GlusterFS is already slow, do you think that NFS on top of it can improve something in the performance? If yes, that it's great news. If no... That single node NFS protected by VMware HA is the only way to go

Comment: I have no experience with nfs-ganesha.  If GlusterFS is slow I don't think NFS on top of it would improve performance, but I could be wrong - I guess it depends what is making NFS slow.   A lot likely depends on how far apart your nodes are.